# How to exit a loop when the user presses ^Z

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;
public class Question2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double radius;
        double area;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a radius.");
            radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

            // Calculate area of the circle using PI and radius
            area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);

            // Output area of the circle
            System.out.println("The area with a radius of " + radius +" is " + area);


        }while(keyboard.hasNext());

    }
```

I can exit the loop with a `^Z`. The problem is when I want to iterate some more. When the program reaches the `keyboard.hasNext()` I press enter nothing happens So when I press a number. The next iteration `radis= keyboard.nextDouble()` statement is skipped because the number is in the buffer I assume. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are slightly misunderstanding something here. You have a do{}while(); loop, which is basically do something, then check the statement and then do this something again.

Now, the problem is, that you are entering the loop, and calling `Scanner.nextDouble()`.
The Scanner waits, until it has something to process (That's the reason it works the first time.), if it has this information (the moment you press enter).
It will begin. But after that there is nothing left in the Scanner, so the `Scanner.hasNext()` returns false and you exit the loop and thus the program.

So, instead of checking if there is something, just loop all the time and read from the Scanner.
Since the next() method blocks we don't need to test if there is anything in it.

Something like this does the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double r;
    double a;
    String str;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("please give me a radius: ");
        str = s.nextLine();

        try {
            r = Double.parseDouble(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            break;
        }

        a = Math.PI * r * r;
        System.out.printf("area of a circle with a radius of %f is: %f%n", r, a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is

```
while(keyboard.hasNext());
```

should be

```
while(keyboard.hasNextDouble());
```

I would also prefer to define the variables in the most restricted scope that works (for optimization, and to keep the name space open). Next, I would recommend using formatted output with `printf` instead of building `String` with concatenation. And you could eliminate the call to `Math.pow`. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a radius.");
        double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Calculate area of the circle using PI and radius
        double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;

        // Output area of the circle
        System.out.printf("With a radius of %f the area is %f.%n", radius,
                area);
    } while (keyboard.hasNextDouble());
}
```